# Adding a style attribute without removing the previous styles

Tags: javascript, css

I have 3 different functions that set a specific style attribute to an element, invoked by clicking 3 different buttons, for example:

```
element.setAttribute("style","fill:#00ffff");
element.setAttribute("style","fill:#ff00ff");
element.setAttribute("style","fill:#ffff00");
```

THEN, I have another function invoked by a forth button that updates the style of the same element.

```
element.setAttribute("style", "transform:translate(29.5%,0px)";
```

The problem is that when it updates it, the previous attributes, set by the first 3 functions, are removed, so button no#4 translate the element, but the element loses it's fill.

Since the colors are not fixed, I can't solve it by

```
element.setAttribute("style", "transform:translate(29.5%,0px);fill:#ffff00";
```

I was hoping for a way that ADDS the attribute rather than update it. 
I hope I got everything clear for you guys, any ideas?

No libraries allowed for this problem

Comment: Not saying this is your issue, but your values aren't wrapped with end-quotes, but it's better to go through the `style` property rather than the `style` attribute of the element

Comment: Yes, sorry, it was just an example that I wrote very quickly. Edited.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

from https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp :

### Bad

```js
element.setAttribute("style", "background-color: red;");
```

### Good

```js
element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

By choosing the second way, you only overwrite the thing you need

Comment: It works, thank you. Apparently our teacher taught us the bad method :')

Answer (score 0):

You can use them in this way:-

```
element.setAttribute("style","fill:#00ffff;")
element.setAttribute("style","fill:#ff00ff;")
element.setAttribute("style","fill:#ffff00;")
element.setAttribute('style', `${element.getAttribute("style")} color:red;`)
```